# influtterDart Data Class Generator is not working it is showing: item couldn't be converted to a data class: Class doesn't have unique property names

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio, dart

Dart Data Class Generator is not working it is showing:
item couldn't be converted to a data class: Class doesn't have unique property names